# How to install atom on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: bash, shell, atom-editor, git-bash

I think it is a hard thing to do as nobody was able to help me, if anyone know how to install `atom` on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having with this?

Comment: "bash" is not a platform in which software can be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it as you would on any Ubuntu - from its [`README.md`](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/README.md#debian-linux-ubuntu):

> #### Debian Linux (Ubuntu)
>
> Atom is only available for 64-bit Linux systems.
>
> 1. Download `atom-amd64.deb` from the [Atom releases page](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/latest).
> 2. Run `sudo dpkg --install atom-amd64.deb` on the downloaded package.
> 3. Launch Atom using the installed `atom` command.

The thing is - it won't run. Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is highly experimental yet, so graphic applications won't work. I've tried on a VM, and I get a `libXss.so` not found error. You may be able to fix that issue by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, probably, but you'll hit a bug in the implementation sooner than later.

Anyway, atom runs natively on Windows, so I'm not sure why would you want to install it there.

Comment: In fact, the question was from a tutorial which says `If using Atom, go to Atom > Install shell commands to enable the atom command at the command line`. However, this shortcut is only available on Mac, so I am asking how can I do the same task on Windows?